# Добовление данных в базу данных

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Добрый день!

У меня возник вопрос. Есть в базе данных 3 таблицы: `user`, `items` и `useritems`. Мне нужно сделать запрос к таблице `user` и выяснить, есть ли такой пользователь в базе, если есть, то выводим его `ИМЯ` и все предметы, которые у него есть, а если пользователя нет с таким `ИМЕНЕМ`, то просто выводим сообщение, что пользователь добавлен в базу данных и автоматически добавить ему предмет.

В таблице `useritems` у меня 3 поля `id`, `uid`, и `itmid` и теперь я не могу понять, как добавить туда пользователя и присвоить ему любой предмет из таблицы `items`. Так как у меня при клике на кнопку добавляется только пользователь в таблицу `user`.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`uname`) VALUES ('$nambreUsuario');
```

А вот как добавить предмет и пользователя в таблицу `useritems` я ума не приложу.
И при этом надо, чтобы и в таблице `user`, и таблице `useritems` пользователь был под одним `id`.

Comment: Откройте для себя FOREIGN KEY %)

Comment: Проблема была решина всем спасибо за советыю

А решил я так : 

 <pre><code>$sql = "INSERT INTO `players` (`uname`) VALUES ('$nambreUsuario')";
        $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `playerittemtype` (`player`,`itemtype`) VALUES ('$id' , 1)";

        $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());</code></pre>
и все заработало без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень интересно получается. Как добавить запись в таблицу user Вы знаете, а как в таблицу useritems - не знаете. Это юмор у Вас такой?=) Если нет, то ответ: точно так же как и в таблицу user. Будь я на Вашем месте - создал бы так же 3 таблицы.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;    
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;    
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';    
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;      
USE `mydb`;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (    
  `iduser` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,    
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`) ,    
  UNIQUE INDEX `ix_user_name` () )    
ENGINE = InnoDB    
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8    
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`item` (    
  `iditem` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,    
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`iditem`) )    
ENGINE = InnoDB    
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8    
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user_has_item` (    
  `user_iduser` INT(11) NOT NULL ,    
  `item_iditem` INT(11) NOT NULL ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_iduser`, `item_iditem`) ,    
  INDEX `fk_user_has_item_item1` (`item_iditem` ASC) ,    
  INDEX `fk_user_has_item_user` (`user_iduser` ASC) ,    
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_item_user`    
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_iduser` )    
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user` (`iduser` )    
    ON DELETE NO ACTION    
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,    
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_item_item1`    
    FOREIGN KEY (`item_iditem` )    
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`item` (`iditem` )    
    ON DELETE NO ACTION    
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)    
ENGINE = InnoDB    
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8    
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;    
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;    
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Связь насколько я понял у Вас должна быть "много-ко-многим". Я сделал так. На user.name вешаем UNIQUE, движок InnoDB, внешние ключи и всё прочее.

Добавлять Вы всё же умеете) INSERT INTO `table` (...) VALUES (...)
Вообще очень рекомендую ознакомиться со всеми [возможностями SQL](http://www.sql.ru/docs/).

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться

Answer (score 3):

Перед тем, как производить запросы к базе данных нужно правильно спроектировать эту базу. В частности, установить связи между таблицами. Для этого нужно использовать дополнительные поля в таблицах - внешние ключи. В вашем случае, на сколько я понял, в таблице `useritems` это поле `uid`. При ее создании, после перечня полей с их описанием допишите `FOREIGN KEY(uid)`.

Самый простой способ, при условии, что у Вас там все правильно построено, такой:

- На странице находятся текстовые поля (информация о пользователе)
- выпадающий список с предметами. Поскольку для предметов есть таблица, и пользователю нужно только выбрать предмет, то этот список формируется в результате выборки всех предметов из таблицы предметов. При этом очень важно хранить также id предмета, например можно сделать так
   **`<option value="id_predmet">Предмет`**
- Тогда после добавления пользователя, Вам нужно сделать следующие действия:
      -- Выбираем из таблицы пользователей только что созданную запись. Это нужно сделать, т.к. в таблице useritems должен храниться не сам пользователь,, а его id, а насколько я понимаю - он у Вас auto increment, т.е. вормируется автоматически. Для выбора можно использовать следующий код
      SELECT uid FROM users WHERE фамилия='той фамилии, что ввел пользователь в текстовое поле при добавлении последнего человека' AND имя='то имя которое ввели в текстовое поле' и т.д.
- Добавляем в таблицу useritems новую запись с полученным uid и выбранным в списке id_predmet

Конечно этот способ не самый быстрый, можно также использовать сложные вложенные запросы, но для начала нужно разобраться с их синтаксисом

Comment: FOREIGN KEY(uid) это все понятно , а как теперь правельно запрос поставить????

Comment: Если хотите как ТРУ сделать - создайте вьюшку в которой обьединяете все эти таблицы в 1у и вставляйте данные в нее как в 1у табличку ^^

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться

Comment: php.su -там есть много материала на эту тему с примерами